# Prove if $\gcd(a,7) = 1$ then $a^3 - 1$ or $a^3 + 1$ is divisible by 7

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to prove if $$\gcd(a,7) = 1$$ then $$a^3 - 1$$ or $$a^3 + 1$$ is divisible by 7. (Using Little Fermat Theorem.)

Obviously, $a^6 = 1 (\bmod 7)$, but how do I use that in this instance?

Answer (score 4):

Use $a^6 -1 = (a^3 - 1)(a^3+1)$ and that $7$ is prime. Now $7$ divides $a^6-1$, so...

Comment: Thanks! :) @John Ma Don't really know how I missed that.

Comment: @Sara : You are wellcome~